# form.action assignment - object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript, jsp

JSP

```
<form:form id="myForm" action="myAction.html" name="sws" commandName="myModel" method="POST">
    .
    .
    </form:form>
```

Javascript

```
var currentForm=document.getElementById("myForm");
currentForm.target = '_self';
currentForm.action = 'myAction2.html';
currentForm.submit();
```

I am getting error `object doesn't support this property or method` in IE 7, at line --> currentForm.action = 'myAction2.html';

Comment: IE7? Are you really running XP?

Comment: `.getElementById("myForm")`?

Comment: @sp00m Sorry that was copy paste error due to id change as I am dealing with proprietary code. That's not actually the issue. Still stuck.

Comment: @PaulDraper The App is supposed to be compatible at least in an IE 7 browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing Javascript code with the following jquery code solved the problem. I would still like to know, how and why.

```
$("#myForm").attr({'target': '_self' , 'action': '/MyApp/forms/MyAction2.html'}).submit();
```